# Substance Painter: Fix color addition

Tags: color, blending, substance-engine

Substance Painter appears to add colors together wrongly when selecting "Normal Blending Mode"

The right side is what photoshop does correctly, meaning R+G+B values in the border region never exceed 255. On the left side is what Substance Painter does incorrectly, the green dot appears to have a glow around it.

[image]

If there is no quick way to fix this, I will have to export Red and Green and Blue layers individually and blend them together in Photoshop.

[image]

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps to reproduce your Substance Painter example?

Comment: @DMGregory Added a picture. It's just 2 layers with a mask. It's just like in Photoshop.

Comment: Hey @AzulShiva, we have exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution within Substance Painter?

Comment: @Florent I didn't

Comment: Right-side looks incorrect to me, it has a clear black-ish circle.

Comment: @Kromster It's mathematically incorrect. At 50% transparency of the red layer you should have RGB(128, 128, 0). In Substance Painter you have RGB(192, 192, 0).

Comment: [128, 128, 0] is incorrect because it doesn't take into account gamma correction. [186, 186, 0] is about where it should be.

Answer (score 2):

From provided image, left variant looks like to be more correct (meaning evenly bright). Where's right variant has a clearly noticeable black-ish circle.

We can also check out the desaturated image (Photoshop -> Adjustments -> Desaturate) on the left looks more even in brightness. Of course even better desaturator would be using color perception ratios (of 0.299R + 0.587G + 0.144B, which is not the case in this case).

[image]

To the explanation: IIRC mathematical approach to color handling is not correct, since the colors are written down in non-linear scale.

Aforementioned median result of 192 could be related to calculation being made in sRGB colorspace. If the gamma is set to be default 2.2, then (1^2.2 / 2)^(1/2.2) * 255 = 186, seems kinda close.

So yeah, Painter seems to be doing a better job at accurately mixing colors. Can it be "fixed"? I can not say, sorry.

Comment: There are still a few possible reasons why you might want to do gamma-naïve blending. For instance, maybe you want to replicate the output of another program that does the wrong blending, such as a browser. Or maybe the raw RGB numbers are being interpreted as some other kind of mathematical objects, such as for a normal map, and you need a mathematical average.

Comment: Exactly, I'm using the RGB numbers for a shader I programmed myself, for layering several textures over each other based on the RGB map. (Imagine a dirt path along nature, or icy mountain tops for a terrain map)

Comment: @AzulShiva ah, using them as masks, not as RGB textures. I'm not sure if Painter can mix/generate outputs in linear colorspace rather than sRGB. Another thing you can try is to pre-process Painter textures in your game to convert tham back from sRGB to linear: `R = (R/255)^(1/2.2)*255`.

Comment: @Kromster Why haven't I thought of that... I mean they are my own shaders lol